# I am not able to access local variable outside function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code. I am not able to access local variable outside the function even i have initialized before the function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

var output;

getJSONResult();

function getJSONResult(){
    jQuery.getJSON( 'https://isitup.org/nearhero.com.json', function( data ) {
        output = data.response_code;
        alert(output); // It gives output 405 (that i want outside the function)
    });
}

alert(output); // I am not able to access output 405 here and its gives output undefined


</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pretty sure it's returning a promise object.

Comment: you need to look into promises async/await

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not using this call asynchronously, I'd probably suggest switching to `$.ajax` as the helper function getJSON is a huge PITA and is almost never used. This will do the same exact thing you're looking for. :)

```js
getJSONResult();
var output;

function getJSONResult() {
  jQuery.ajax({
  url: 'https://isitup.org/nearhero.com.json',
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false,
  success: function(data) {
    output = data;
    console.log(output);
    } 
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Now, it is not giving any alert to check output

Comment: Are you sure you're ever receiving the data?

Comment: Yes im sure. after using async i'm not getting data. check here please https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GES25UFSNYUB

Answer (score 1):

Try using promise

```
var output;

function getJSONResult(){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    jQuery.getJSON( 'https://isitup.org/nearhero.com.json', function( data ) {
      result = data.response_code;
      resolve(result);
  });
  });
}

getJSONResult().then((result) => {
  output = result;
  alert(result);
});
```